# Teamcity snapshot dependency : how to prevent running the build which is already passed

Tags: teamcity

Here's the scenario: I have a TeamCity "master" build that aggregates the results of  other 11 builds.
I'm using snapshot dependencies.
This works fine in normal scenario.But in case, any of the dependent sub build fails and master build is triggered again then all 11 dependent builds get triggered.I want only failed build to be triggered not all.
Is there any way to achieve this??

Answer (score 1):

1. Normally, if the source code for any of the 11 dependent fields has not changes ,they will be queued but will just silently go to success
2. In case you just need artefacts from the previous builds, you can try setting up artefacts dependencies instead of snapshot dependencies. That way you can rerun an intermediate target if it fails and still continue for the rest of the chain. By the way if you are setting artefact dependencies you also have to add "Finish run triggers" on the targets
3. Also, when setting snapshot dependencies, there is an option "Do not run new if there is a suitable one". Please enable it to see if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

In TC 8, some settings will interfere with build reusing. From the docs:

> Some settings in VCS roots can effectively disable builds reusing.
> These settings are:
>
> Subversion: Checkout, but ignore changes mode
>
> CVS: Checkout by tag mode
>
> Perforce: Checkout by label set to Client instead of Client mapping
>
> Starteam: checkout mode option set to view label or promotion date

(source: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Snapshot+Dependencies)